# When talking to Parse server (using Swift on iOS), why PFFileObject keeps returning nil?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

Why does PFFileObject keeps giving me an error like `Foundation._GenericObjCError.nilError` and if I use `PFFileObject(name:data:)` to create a file object, I will get `nil`.

My code looks like:

```
func uploadImageFileToParseServer(image: UIImage, uid: String) {
        guard let imageData = image.pngData() else {
            UILogger.error("Null imageData")
            return
        }
        UILogger.log("creating imageFile using \(uid) and \(imageData) under name \(uid)-img.png")
        
        let unwrappedImageFile = try? PFFileObject(name: "\(uid)-img.png", data: imageData, contentType: "image/png")

        unwrappedImageFile?.saveInBackground { (result, error) in
            if let error = error{
                UILogger.error("\(String(describing: error))")
            } else {
                let query = PFQuery(className: "User")
                UILogger.log("Saving to User with uid \(uid)")
                query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: uid)
                query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
                    if let user = objects {
                        for object in user {
                            UILogger.log("User \(uid) found. Updating his/her avatar column now")
                            object["avatar"] = unwrappedImageFile
                            object.saveInBackground { isSuccessful, error in
                                if !isSuccessful {
                                    UILogger.error("Error in updating User - \(error.debugDescription)")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you try with `let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)`?

Comment: Thanks. It won't pass though. The compiler will give me: `'UIImagePNGRepresentation' has been replaced by instance method 'UIImage.pngData()'`.

Comment: Do you see `UILogger.error("Null imageData")` being printed on logs?

Comment: Yes, Davi. Anyway for now we decided to use S3 for storage and only save the url in Parser server. (Or until we figured out...)